# about helm yaml syntax

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

the configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}-config-map
data:
  brokerConf: |
    {{ .Values.configmap }}
```

the below values.yaml is right.

```
configmap: |
  key=values
```

but the values.yaml is wrong

```
configmap: |
  key=values
  key2=values2
```

the helm template core content is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config-map
data:
  brokerConf: |
    key=values
key2=values2
```

the error

```
Error: YAML parse error on test/templates/config-map.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: could not find expected ':'
helm.go:84: [debug] error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: could not find expected ':'
YAML parse error on v5-proxy/templates/config-map.yaml
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.(*manifestFile).sort
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:146
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil.SortManifests
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/releaseutil/manifest_sorter.go:106
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Configuration).renderResources
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/action.go:165
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may update the `configmap` as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-map
data:
  brokerConf:
    {{ .Values.configmap| indent 4|trim }}
```

The error is caused because the 2nd line in `data.brokerConf` is not indented properly. Something like below, where `key2=values2` is an invalid statement in yaml world, the correct is `key2: values2`.

```
configmap: 
  key=values
key2=values2
```

To fix it we have to use `indent`, but it will do indent the first line additionally. To [address that](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/issues/54#issuecomment-360572045), `trim` is used.